# Automatically create topic with ( LDA,HDP) ?

Tags: machine-learning, lda

I am working on CV (Curriculum Vitae) for classification, I have used LDA.
My result over 3 different concepts of CV (Marketing, Computer, Communication) by setting (N=3) was good. 
Now the question is, how can I create new Topic (of course by adding it to the existing topics) for new CV with concept of Finance (or maybe other concept)?

In fact my aim is to generate new topic each time to get new concept.

I'm getting different CV every day with different concept and I have doubt on choosing which algorithm (HDP, On_Line LDA) could be useful to do my classification automatic.

Answer (score 0):

LDA or other topic models are not classification methods. They should be seen as dimensionality reduction/preprocessing/synonym discovery methods in the context of supervised learning: instead of representing a document to a classifier as a bag of words, you represent it as its posterior over the topics. Don't assume that because you have 3 classes in your classification task you choose 3 topics for LDA. Topic model parameters should be set to best model the documents (as measured by perplexity, or some other quality metric of the topic model, check David Mimno's recent work for other possibilities), and the vector of topic probabilities/posterior parameters (or whatever you think is useful) should then be fed to a supervised learning method.

You'll see this is exactly the experimental set up followed by Blei et al in the original LDA paper.

Comment: I tested LDA_Gibbas sampler by choosing the number of Topic (In environement R) and for new document(of course with new dictionary) i used correlated Topic.I mean's for each new documents i should fixed the number of topic (it is my first difficulty)and i tested with correlated Topic (i did it before).How can i integerated the correlated topic with the existing topics ?(here is my second difficulty).

Comment: For solve my problem i wrote a fusion function for integration the exiting topics with correlated topic,This function compare exiting topics with the correlated topic and the words that are not in either of them it will palced in new Topic (but this way it not good)!